# Plotting interaction term in logistic regression for multiply imputed data in R

Tags: r, plot, interaction, imputation

I am trying to plot a significant interaction effect in logistic regression:
   IV: categorical variable (4 levels (categorical factor))
   Moderator: Continuous variable
   DV: Binary variable (level1=0, level 2=1)

Using MICE, missing data was multiply imputed. I would like to plot the significant interaction effect (reference class vs. class #3 is significant), preferably in R. See output below, CATIV3:MOD:

> ```
> fit=with(data=iX, glm(BINARYDV~CATIV+MOD+CATIV*MOD, family=binomial(link = 
> "logit"),contrasts=list(CATIV=contr.treatment(4,base=1, contrasts=TRUE, 
> sparse=FALSE))))
>
> summary(pool(fit0))
>
>                est        se          t       df    Pr(>|t|) 
> (Intercept)  0.06452198 0.1790517  0.3603539 370.8042 0.718787694 
>
>  CATIV2      0.43549899 0.3154679  1.3804859 372.3877 0.168265145 
>  CATIV3        0.81897482 0.4277301  1.9147002 291.8157 0.056508371 
>  CATIV4        0.36566370 0.2774047  1.3181598 380.6421 0.188242828 
>  MOD           0.54166219 0.1885668  2.8725219 369.8421 0.004306882  
>  CATIV2:MOD    -0.15249583 0.3494152 -0.4364316 341.1353 0.662799672 
>  CATIV3:MOD -1.19005755 0.4008051 -2.9691678 271.3438 **0.003252996** 
>  CATIV4:MOD    -0.09664339 0.2975578 -0.3247886 314.4871 0.745556987
> ```

Unfortunately, I was not able to produce a reproducible example. The code would look something like:

> f1=with(data=Mnhanes, glm(hyp~age+chl+age*chl, family=binomial(link = "logit"),contrasts=list(age=contr.treatment(3,base=1, contrasts=TRUE, sparse=FALSE))))

My questions are:

(1) What is the best way to plot the significant interaction effects for imputed data in R?

(2) Would a package like interplot (function: interplot.lmmi) would produce a plot with the dichotomous outcome? The manual does not provide an example--I would appreciate a (more) user friendly example (i.e., how to simply input MICE generated objects)

(3) Are there any other ways of reporting this effect (again using multiply imputed data) besides a plot of simple slopes? If so, are there online tools that make this possible outside of R?